# convert string double quotes to single quotes

Tags: php, string

I get a password from database and it is stored in the `$password` variable with "" (Double quotes). I want to change the `$password` variable value with '' (single quotes). How can I change this? When I test with a static value, `$password = '$2y$10$wFgLkiJbc7MQ0aY6H7bZwehm45CFlvpSBvZmHs9m8euqPmDlP0mIK';` it is ok and the password is valid. My problem is look like this link.

[php password_hash and password_verify issues no match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855715/php-password-hash-and-password-verify-issues-no-match?answertab=votes#tab-top)

How to solve $password?

```
$password = $result['Password'];
```

This is my code:

```
$get_email = $_POST['email'];
$get_password = $_POST['password'];

$result = $conn->prepare("select * from user where Email='$get_email'");
$result->execute();

    foreach ($result as $result) {
        $id = $result['ID'];
        $password = $result['Password'];


        if (password_verify($get_password, $password)) {
            echo 'Password is valid!';
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid password.';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is `code` quotes? With the formatting of the question I don't know what is code and what the question is. I also don't know what "code" is in your explanation and title.

Comment: I already edit my question. Please help me. :)

Comment: ' and " is quotes in english. Do you mean quotes by code? If not, what do you mean by Double code and single code?

Comment: Or you mean that password hashed double times?

Comment: Sorry, I mean quotes. How to change string double quotes to single quotes. When I test with $password = '$2y$10$wFgLkiJbc7MQ0aY6H7bZwehm45CFlvpSBvZmHs9m8euqPmDlP0mIK'; Password is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use double quotes it will be used as a variable because of there was '$' in your string, while when you use single quotes it will be used as a char

Answer (score 0):

At the moment i can propose you only one idea.
What about modify a bit your mysql query?
Something like

```
$conn->prepare("select * from user where Email='$get_email'" and `Password` = '$get_password');
```

If this query will return empty result you can show 'Invalid password'.
Not very good solution, but should work.

Comment: $get_password is original password and not same in the database password because of hash function. :)

Comment: in this case just use something like this
    $password = password_hash($get_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
and insert variable $password in your mysql query

Comment: No. My problem is like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855715/php-password-hash-and-password-verify-issues-no-match?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: When I test with $password = '$2y$10$wFgLkiJbc7MQ0aY6H7bZwehm45CFlvpSBvZmHs9m8euqPmDlP0mIK'; Password is valid.

Comment: Sure, but your goal is check password, isn't it?
For a first look you can check it on mysql side only,  because in example password  "$2y$10$qTfvt1KJzslkXGG.o.f6YOiWnV7TX8G4PaUo0zmU84RzAaETsLaia" 
php interprets like few variables. And this variables are udefined.

Why don't you want to change mysql query?

Comment: I can't write like these 
`$conn->prepare("select * from user where Email='$get_email'" and `Password` = '$get_password');`
because `$password = password_hash($get_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` is not same result. My password is 123456. When I register twice with two account, hash are not same. So, I can't change mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with my code. I retrieve the **hashed password** **from database** and then use the `password_verify()` to verify it against **entered password**. In order for the code to work with no problem the hashed password retrieved from the database must be **trimmed** using `trim()`. Sample code here:

```
public function verifylogin() {
        //this is an array with user credentials from login form 
        $usercred = $this->input->post();

        //this will check in user model and return password, etc. where name is equal to entered name
        $userdb = $this->User_model->check($usercred);
        $userdbpass = trim($userdb[0]['pass']); //trim is very critical !!!

       //now we check if the text pass is equal to hashed one
        if (password_verify($usercred['password'], $userdbpass)) {
            $sess_data = array('login' => TRUE, 'username' => $usercred['username'], 'type' => $usercred['type']);
            $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            redirect(base_url());
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Wrong Username or Password!');
            //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect(base_url() . 'users/login');
        }
    }
```